# C++ , Erasing Vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct

i'm new in cpp.I defined a vector with this code and in the end , i want to erase it completely.

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct MCLASS
{
    string *a = new string();
    string *b = new string();

    MCLASS(string ax,string bx)
    {
        a = new string(ax);
        b = new string(bx);
    }

    ~MCLASS()
    {
        delete a;
        delete b;
    }
};

vector<MCLASS*> *vc = new vector<MCLASS*>;




int main()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= 1000000 ; i++)
        vc->push_back(new MCLASS("EHEM","UHUM"));

    for (int i = 0 ; i <= 1000000 ; i++)
        delete vc->at(i);

    vc->clear();
    delete vc;
    cout<<"Deleted";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

but there is a problem.I can't erase it completely.I tried to delete each items of vector , clear vector items , and delete it.but when i check the RAM Usage of this application , it uses about 130MB.Please explain to me what to do.Thanks!

Comment: You need to read about memory model of your operation system. In short: Most of the time arena is not reduced to have better performance.

Comment: You should not use all those pointers...

Comment: You can alleviate these pointer issues by not using *raw pointer* and declaring variables without `new`.  If you *must* use pointers use *smart pointers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `new string` twice per member variable. For each one, the result of the second call to `new string` overwrites the result of the first, so the first never gets `delete`d and there's your memory leak.

Don't call `new string` in the declaration of `a` and `b`—only in the constructor.

```
struct MCLASS
{
    string *a;
    string *b;
...
```

Comment: Or, better yet, use a member variable: `struct MCLASS { string a,b; MCLASS(string ax, string bx) { a = ax; b = bx; } .... }`

Comment: majk is right of course, there's no actual need to allocate heap memory explicitly. It's better practice (not least because it helps avoid leaks) to use container objects directly rather than pointers to them.  But, provided every `new` is balanced by a `delete`, that's not the source of problem you're reporting.

Comment: Yeah you are right.i was wrong.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

From cplusplus.com's [article](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) on `vector::clear`:

> A reallocation is not guaranteed to happen, and the vector capacity is not guaranteed to change due to calling this function. A typical alternative that forces a reallocation is to use swap:
>   `vector<T>().swap(x);   // clear x reallocating`

As VladimirS suggested in his comment; memory management is not a simple beast, however the above should reduce your memory consumption provided nothing has prevented that by replacing delete (such as some memory inspection tools).

Comment: Yes but error is not here in this case. I post an answer explaining his error. @Alexei Barnes

Comment: @N0un That's true but this question is poorly formed and is actually several questions, I've answered one part and that answer tackles another side of the issue.

Comment: Yes, and your post is interesting!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to erase all contents of a `std::vector` you can either call the [clear](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) member function or [resize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) it to zero size.

There's a slight difference in result. `clear` will destroy all elements but (likely) preserve the vectors capacity. `resize(0)` will destroy all elements and also reduce capacity to zero.

Comment: This does not call delete on its members in case it contains pointers, which would lead to memory leaks.

Comment: I'd argue that if it contains pointers and one wants them deleted (as in, the vector *owns* the pointers), then the vector *should* have been holding smart pointers and that's then the bug you should be fixing.

Comment: You're absolutely right about that. Just wanted to include that for the sake of completeness.

Comment: It's works! resize(0) decreased memory usage to 0.8MB :)) you saved my life.

Comment: Then accept the answer, please. If it solved your problem. Happy to have been able to help you :)

Comment: "accepted as true answer" - apparently not for long.

Comment: Oh sorry i was wrong when i seeing the ram usage.the problem was re-allocation a and b strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your error takes place on lines 10-11 :

```
string *a = new string();
string *b = new string();
```

Indeed, you create two pointers ***a*** and ***b*** and you **allocate** memory for them, memory you'll never **free** because you re-allocate new memory in the constructor without checking values.

Proper way to fix that (and good practice) is to initialize pointers attributes to ***NULL***. In your case replace these lines like that:

```
string *a = NULL;
string *b = NULL;
```

then, allocate it in constructor or somewhere...

**Tips**:

- Before a ***new*** or a ***delete***, check current values ;)
- Use ***Valgrind*** or a tool like that to check memory leak